# I want to simulate a random sample of length n from DAG of correlated Bernoulli's

Tags: r, sampling, inference, bernoulli-distribution, dag

Suppose I have a DAG of 4 vertices. Each vertex consists of a Bernoulli of parameter $p$.

It is the following:
(Z) ---> (Y) 
(Z) ---> (W)
(X) --->  (Y) ---> (W)

I hope it is clear. Anyway, I managed to find the joint density function which is the following: 
$$ f(x,y,z,w) = f_x(x) * f_z(z) * f_y|(x,z)(y | x,z) * f_w|(y,z)(w|y,z)
$$
Now my problem is that I want to find a random sample of length n from this graph. I am struggling to see what it means to have a sample of length $n$: do I have to find $n$ values of the density function in random points?

Anyway, do you know how I can do this in `R`? Especially the conditional part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be confused, so maybe you should look first at some simpler situations. I will interpret *random sample of size $n$* to mean to simulate (or "draw") $n$ (some positive  integer) realization of some random variable. So, if that random variable (rv) is Bernoulli with some probability $p$, a realization must be one of the possible values 0 or 1. A random sample of size 10 in `R`:

```
 rbinom(10,1,0.75)
 [1] 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1
```

Here the probability of the value 1 was choosen as 0.75.

A sample from your DAG will be a vector of length 4, which in your case will be all 0 or 1's. A random sample of size 10 will be a collection of 10 such 4-vectors, which could conveniently be given as a $10\times 4$-matrix.

To draw one such 4-vector, you must use the structure of the DAG, as given in your factored probability mass function (pmf).  In your formula
$$
   f(x,y,z,w) = f_x(x) * f_z(z) * f_y|(x,z)(y | x,z) * f_w|(y,z)(w|y,z)
$$
there is no conditioning in the first two factors, so you start by drawing $X,Z$ (you must specify two probabilities first). The third factor conditions on $X,Z$, so can be drawn now (but you need to specify a probability parameter that depends on $x,z$). Finally you can draw $W$ from the last factor in the same way.  An example where I use as full specification
$$\DeclareMathOperator{\P}{\mathbb{P}}
   \P(X=1)=p=0.75,\quad \P(Z=1)=q=0.5,\quad \P(Y=1\mid X=x,Z=z)=p_y(x,z),\quad \P(W=1\mid Y=y,Z=z)=p_w(y,z)
$$
and then I will use for example:
$$
p_y(x,z)= 0.1+\frac{x+z}{3},\\
p_w(y,z)= 0.2+\frac{y+z}{3}
$$
`R` code for **one** draw:

```
draw_1_from_DAG <- function() {
      x  <-  rbinom(1,1,0.75)
      z  <-  rbinom(1,1,0.5)
      y  <-  rbinom(1,1,0.1+(x+z)/3)
      w  <-  rbinom(1,1,0.2+(y+z)/3)
      c(x=x,z=z,y=y, w=w)
}
```

One example call:

```
  draw_1_from_DAG()
x z y w 
1 0 1 1
```

And for a sample of size 10:

```
  replicate(10,draw_1_from_DAG())
  [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
x    1    0    1    0    1    1    1    1    1     1
z    0    1    0    1    1    0    1    0    1     1
y    0    1    1    1    1    0    1    1    0     1
w    0    1    1    1    1    0    0    0    1     1
```

Comment: Wow, this is the clearest answer I have ever seen. Thank you very much. I just have one last doubt: Is there a "standard" way to define $p_y(x,z)$ and $p_w(y,z)$? Like maybe using Bayes theorem to find the probability of the conditional event?